# AngularJS Comma separated assignment using q.defer object

Tags: angularjs

[Angular Django Registration Auth - djangoAuth.js](https://github.com/Tivix/angular-django-registration-auth/blob/master/app/scripts/services/djangoAuth.js)

In lines 25 through 29, a comma separated assignment takes place. When you separate each line by semi-colons instead of commas, the code no longer works. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and when you do that have you tried to put var before defining each variable? maybe it could be that. It seems to be a multiple declarative statement, then in order to make it work with semicolons you have to put it this way :

```
var deferred = $q.defer(),
var url = this.API_URL + args.url;
var method = args.method || "GET";
params = params;
var data = args.data || {};
```